# make 'Display can be toggled' conditional in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that I run both directly and as a subreport.
It has several rows, each toggled by the previous so it open with a summary line, but you can open a list of SOs and then open each SO.

This all works fine when run in SSRS, but directly and as a subreport where the subreport itself is by default hidden and can be toggled (so 3 layers of toggling possible)

However, when I export to Excel, though the subreport is by default hidden, when I hit the + or the 2 to expand a layer, the subreport opens all at once instead of with the 2 layers hidden waiting for toggling.

I read somewhere that Excel has a limit of toggling layers, but I thought it was 9.. not 2.

I would be satisfied with being able to have it conditionally disable toggling in the subreport, ie, have all but the summary line permanently hidden when I set a parameter to 'subreport style' and the renderer is excel.. but I don't see how to do that.

..Short of duplicating the table and 'filtering' each into suppression through manipulation of the above conditions.. but that.. would *really* not be optimal.

I've spent quite a bit of time looking for conditional use of that 'Display can be toggled' feature, but google's breakdown of the search terms takes me to the several ways to toggle.  Or hide the toggling + (which I'd thought briefly might shut excel down, but no dice).

Appreciate any help!

Comment: You can setup your toggling on expression and check if Globals!RenderFormat is “EXCEL“ disable it.

Comment: I assume you mean put an expression in a textbox then set the toggle to use the textbox.   But I don't see where to use the Render check to disable it.  The expression you put in the textbox will either be true or not and cause toggling.. and I already tried setting that textbox to Hidden.  Still exported to excel.